# Flutter firebase CollectionGroup denied query request

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want want to query a collection group in flutter firebase but after indexing the sub collection when I call eg.`collectionreference.firestore.collectionGroup("publicUser").get()`

I get an error saying I haven't index or the operation is denied

Comment: Those are usually two separate error messages, but it's really hard to say what's going wrong without seeing both the exact error message, and the minimal security rules with which you get that error. Until you update your question to include those, the best we can do is recommend reading the documentation on collection group queries and security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules

Answer (score 0):

Just a silly suggestion... but if the operation results in permission denied - try to remove all security rules, make the database insecure for a second while you make the `collectionGroup` query - hopefully, you'll get an error that there is no index along with a URL that you can copy and paste - this will automatically create the required index. Then, secure your database again (;